# Ubuntu session crashes: Gdk-WARNING: gnome-session: Fatal IO error 11

Tags: gnome, xorg, ati, 64-bit, radeon

This happens on an Acer 7535 notebook with an AMD Athlon 64 X2 cpu and ATI radeon HD3200 graphics, Ubuntu 12.40 64-bit.

Every now and then, the unity 2D session crashes and the user is sent to the login screen.

It seems to happen frequently when restarting firefox.

These are two parts of the syslog I found related to the crash:

```
Jun 18 12:30:53 Aspire-7535 kernel: [ 4794.917287] [fglrx] IRQ 18 Disabled
Jun 18 12:30:53 Aspire-7535 gnome-session[3086]: Gdk-WARNING: gnome-session: Fatal IO error 11 (Ressource temporairement non disponible) on X server :0.#012
Jun 18 12:30:53 Aspire-7535 kernel: [ 4795.002229] show_signal_msg: 36 callbacks suppressed
Jun 18 12:30:53 Aspire-7535 kernel: [ 4795.002235] firefox[8721]: segfault at c ip 00007f5ca6f50cc0 sp 00007fff28fc3ec8 error 4 in libxcb-glx.so.0.0.0[7f5ca6f43000+15000]
Jun 18 12:30:53 Aspire-7535 acpid: client 2890[0:0] has disconnected
Jun 18 12:30:53 Aspire-7535 acpid: client connected from 8737[0:0]
Jun 18 12:30:53 Aspire-7535 acpid: 1 client rule loaded
Jun 18 12:30:54 Aspire-7535 kernel: [ 4795.481828] [fglrx] GART Table is not in FRAME_BUFFER range 
Jun 18 12:30:54 Aspire-7535 kernel: [ 4795.482280] [fglrx] Could not enable MSI; System prevented initialization
Jun 18 12:30:54 Aspire-7535 kernel: [ 4795.483242] [fglrx] Firegl kernel thread PID: 8740
Jun 18 12:30:54 Aspire-7535 kernel: [ 4795.483544] [fglrx] Firegl kernel thread PID: 8741
Jun 18 12:30:54 Aspire-7535 kernel: [ 4795.483707] [fglrx] Firegl kernel thread PID: 8742
Jun 18 12:30:54 Aspire-7535 kernel: [ 4795.484101] [fglrx] IRQ 18 Enabled
Jun 18 12:30:54 Aspire-7535 kernel: [ 4795.746103] [fglrx] Gart USWC size:1156 M.
Jun 18 12:30:54 Aspire-7535 kernel: [ 4795.746108] [fglrx] Gart cacheable size:458 M.
Jun 18 12:30:54 Aspire-7535 kernel: [ 4795.746114] [fglrx] Reserved FB block: Shared offset:0, size:1000000 
Jun 18 12:30:54 Aspire-7535 kernel: [ 4795.746118] [fglrx] Reserved FB block: Unshared offset:fffb000, size:5000
```

and an earlier part:

```
Jun 18 11:41:22 Aspire-7535 kernel: [ 1823.743059] [fglrx] IRQ 18 Disabled
Jun 18 11:41:22 Aspire-7535 gnome-session[1448]: Gdk-WARNING: gnome-session: Fatal IO error 11 (Ressource temporairement non disponible) on X server :0.#012
Jun 18 11:41:22 Aspire-7535 acpid: client 1102[0:0] has disconnected
Jun 18 11:41:22 Aspire-7535 acpid: client connected from 2890[0:0]
Jun 18 11:41:22 Aspire-7535 acpid: 1 client rule loaded
Jun 18 11:41:22 Aspire-7535 kernel: [ 1824.069666] [fglrx] GART Table is not in FRAME_BUFFER range 
Jun 18 11:41:22 Aspire-7535 kernel: [ 1824.073399] [fglrx] Could not enable MSI; System prevented initialization
Jun 18 11:41:22 Aspire-7535 kernel: [ 1824.078887] [fglrx] Firegl kernel thread PID: 2892
Jun 18 11:41:22 Aspire-7535 kernel: [ 1824.079097] [fglrx] Firegl kernel thread PID: 2893
Jun 18 11:41:22 Aspire-7535 kernel: [ 1824.079239] [fglrx] Firegl kernel thread PID: 2894
Jun 18 11:41:22 Aspire-7535 kernel: [ 1824.079420] [fglrx] IRQ 18 Enabled
Jun 18 11:41:22 Aspire-7535 kernel: [ 1824.322990] [fglrx] Gart USWC size:1156 M.
Jun 18 11:41:22 Aspire-7535 kernel: [ 1824.322995] [fglrx] Gart cacheable size:458 M.
Jun 18 11:41:22 Aspire-7535 kernel: [ 1824.323002] [fglrx] Reserved FB block: Shared offset:0, size:1000000 
Jun 18 11:41:22 Aspire-7535 kernel: [ 1824.323005] [fglrx] Reserved FB block: Unshared offset:fffb000, size:5000
```

I would like to know if anyone else is having the critical problem, and if someone knows what exactly is causing these crashes, or, even better, what can be done to fix this problem.

PS: *I have noticed this is a very old issue, yet I couldn't find any solution. This issue has been submitted as a bug a number of times. Thanks for not closing this question as being "off-topic".*

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is mostly likely related to this bug.

Please check: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/999191

Answer (score 0):

[Proposed solution] Reinstall video drivers.
[My system] VMWare Player 7.1.0 with Ubuntu 14.04 as guest.
What happened:

- Working in the described system (in Gnome fallback (Metacity) mode) with Firefox + Eclipse IDE + Knopflerfish OSGi (Java dev).
- Apt-get upgrade OpenJDK 6 & 7 a couple of days ago.
- Error started to happen each time I opened those three programs at same time. (in /var/log/syslog: `Gdk-WARNING: gnome-session: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.#012`)
- Removed (with apt-get purge) both OpenJDK and reinstalled only the 7th version. Also reinstalled each one of those programs and checked for updates.
- No matter which Gnome session I started, the error keeps appearing.

After googling for two days I came to the Eduardo B. answer:

> Your problem is mostly likely related to this bug.
>
> Please check: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/999191

that pointed that the main problem could be the graphic driver. Decided to reinstall the driver which (in my case it is contained in the VMWare Tools package). After that, and for three hours since I did it, no problem detected.
Hope it helps.